# Formatting String method

Tags: java

I am trying to create a method that will format a string from the user using a pattern made of 'x' and '-' characters which also comes from the user.

for example 
if the user inputs abcdefg, and the pattern x-x-x-x-x-x-x, 
the output should be a-b-c-d-e-f-g

My problem comes when the user gives a pattern that is longer than the string which always gives me an error.
Thanks in advance.

This is what I got.

```
private static void FormatString() 
    {



        String str,pattern= "";
        int p=0;
        Scanner in1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner in2 = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a String to be formatted");
        str = in1.nextLine();


        System.out.println("Enter pattern");
        pattern = in2.nextLine();
        char [] array1 = pattern.toCharArray();


        int ultindx = str.lastIndexOf(str);

        int ultindx2 = pattern.lastIndexOf(pattern);
        int lenght = pattern.length();
        for(int y = 0; y < lenght; y++)
        {

            if(array1[y] == 'x' )
            {
            array1[y] = str.charAt(p);
            p++;
            }

            else 
                array1[y] = '-';



        }

        System.out.println(array1);
        formattry++;
    }
```

Comment: What is the question? What error are you getting?

Comment: "...which always gives me an error." Which would be what, exactly? Please  always include your stack trace whenever you have a question about an error.

Comment: What is the desired behavior? Do you want to return an error when the format string is too long, adjust the format string to match the length of input, or something else entirely?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if `p<str.length()`. If you do not do it, you get a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the following line:

```
array1[y] = str.charAt(p);
```

When the pattern is longer then the string, the `p` value is bigger then string's length.

You should add additional condition

```
if(array1[y] == 'x' && p < str.length())
{
   array1[y] = str.charAt(p);
   p++;
}
```